# AWK syntax error - what's causing it?

Tags: bash, awk

I have simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
column=${1:-1}
awk ' {colawk='$column'+2; print $colawk}'
awk '(x=4; print $x)'
```

But I have received error:

```
awk: (x=4; print $x)
awk:     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: (x=4; print $x)
awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Why? Code in the previous line works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with using parentheses instead of braces. Try:

```
awk '{x=4; print $x}'
```

instead, as in the following transcript:

```
pax$ echo a b c d e | awk '(x=4; print $x)'
awk: cmd. line:1: (x=4; print $x)
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:2: (x=4; print $x)
awk: cmd. line:2:                ^ unexpected newline or end of string

pax$ echo a b c d e | awk '{x=4; print $x}'
d
```

Answer (score 5):

An AWK program is a series of pattern action pairs, written as:

```
condition { action }
```

where `condition` is typically an expression and `action` is a series of commands.

`print` is not expression but a statement, so it's a **syntax error** as expected.